# How to keep highlighted text in notepad ++ even if I restart my computer?

Tags: notepad++, highlight

I want to highlight text in my notepad++. I already use the mark option. But it is not permanent. Whenever I restart my notepad++, all the markings are gone. Is there any solution that my highlighted text will be there even if I restart my computer?

Comment: No, but you could create a new file, copy that highlighted text into it, and have nothing else in the file but that text. Wouldn't that work?